# Link to app on Windows App Store is not working for windows phone 8.1

Tags: 8.1, store

I have uploaded my app on Windows App store and it has cleared all the phases to publish the app.
Now I am not able to get my app on Windows Store, also when I click my link to app inside Dashboard -> App Management -> App Identity -> links to my app it gives "We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found" error.
How to get the link to my published app?

Comment: It usually takes up to 24h for an app to show up in the store after publishing it.